# google iframe change opacity on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a google maps iframe on my webpage (in contact page), now I am trying to make the iframe showing opacity 60% for example, but when hovering the iframe it becomes 100%.

Example: [Opacity Google iframe](http://themes.fxoffice.net/take5/#!/page_mail)

I was thinking about putting another div on top of the iframe and give it a white color, change opacity top 60% and when hovering it changes to 100%. Not sure if I am doing it right, and where to put the "position: absolute" and "position: relative".

Is this achievable with CSS and HTML only ?

Comment: What is your current CSS and HTML markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added vendor prefixes for opacity, now it should have full browser support. Give it a try.

```
iframe{
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    -moz-opacity: 0.6;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.6;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

iframe:hover{
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    -khtml-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**UPDATE** - to add transitions:

```
iframe{
    transition:all 1s linear; 
    -o-transition:all 1s linear; 
    -moz-transition:all 1s linear; 
    -webkit-transition:all 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: it works! Do you know maybe how to add a little transition of a sec between the opacity 60 and 100 ? Looks kinda better :D